# MobileFirst Container CLI Extensions are not installed

Tags: docker, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, mobilefirst-cli

Im trying to create docker MobileFirst Server 7.1 image and i wanna upload to Blumix. so, basically i have installed below things in my windows 10

> 1. docker Engine
> 2. Cloud Foundry CLI
> 3. IBM Containers Plugin (cf ic)
> 4. MobileFirst CLI and cf ibm-containers-windows_x64.exe

**cf ibm-container plugins**

```
$ cf plugins
Listing Installed Plugins...
OK

Plugin Name      Version   Command Name        Command Help
IBM-Containers   0.8.889   ic                  IBM Containers plug-in

dev_mode         1.1.0     mode                Show the application mode and runtime status, change the mode to dev or normal
dev_mode         1.1.0     update-file         Update files in the remote application
dev_mode         1.1.0     delete-file         Delete file or directory in the remote application
dev_mode         1.1.0     delete-files        Delete files in the remote application
dev_mode         1.1.0     start-inplace       Start the remote application without destroying the container
dev_mode         1.1.0     stop-inplace        Stop the remote application without destroying the container
dev_mode         1.1.0     restart-inplace     Restart the remote application without destroying the container
dev_mode         1.1.0     invoke-handler      Invoke the handler in the remote application container
dev_mode         1.1.0     apply-increment     Apply increment change in the remote application container
dev_mode         1.1.0     start-utility       Start the application's utility
dev_mode         1.1.0     stop-utility        Stop the application's utility
dev_mode         1.1.0     restart-utility     Restart the application's utility
dev_mode         1.1.0     query-utility       query the application's utility
dev_mode         1.1.0     install-utility     install the application's utility
dev_mode         1.1.0     uninstall-utility   uninstall the application's utility
```

i  configured all the properties file in ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval and when i run **"./initenv.sh args/initenv.properties"** from docker engine it

```
$ ./initenv.sh args/initenv.properties

Checking if MobileFirst Containers CLI is installed ...

MobileFirst Container CLI Extensions are not installed
Try running ./installcontainercli.sh
```

then i tried

```
> $ ./installcontainercli.sh which: no mfp in      
> (/c/Users/skeintech/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Users/skeintech/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/skeintech/bin:/c/Program
> Files
> (x86)/Lenovo/FusionEngine:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program
> Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common
> Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/c/Program
> Files/CloudFoundry:/cmd:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files
> (x86)/IBM/IBM Bluemix Live Sync CLI:/c/Program
> Files/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI:/c/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Utilities
> 1.6:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/Program Files/Cloud Foundry:/c/Users/skeintech/AppData/Roaming/Cloud Foundry:/c/Program
> Files/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI:/c/Program Files/Docker
> Toolbox:/c/Users/skeintech/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files
> (x86)/Microsoft VS
> Code/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
> MobileFirst Platform CLI is not installed
```

Answer (score 3):

The zip that you are using: *ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval* refers to IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Evaluation image. This has been discontinued and not available anymore.

You should consider using **IBM MobileFirst Foundation v8.0**, by using the **Mobile Foundation Bluemix service**: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mobile-foundation

For development and testing, the service has a **Developer plan** which allows you to use the Mobile Foundation server free for 365 hours a month.

Learn more about the service [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/).

However, if you need to deploy the 7.1 version of MobileFirst Platform onto Bluemix, use the customization zip. Here is the [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/) .

**Note:** You will need entitlement to download the MobileFirst Platform Foundation v7.1 customization zip.